# Subscription Method of a Subscriber in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, list, subscriber

I'm in need of Subscriber source details. As I'm going through each report, I found List demographics give Subscription method details but not at the subscriber level. Do we have any feature in the Marketing cloud that will fetch the source of the subscriber? Also what are all the subscription methods available on the platform?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing OOTB that would log the exact source of the subscriber. The only feature that would be close, is the `Add Method` field in the All Subscribers list, but I am not sure it will give you the level of detail you need:

[image]

Some of the possible values include: Unspecified, Webcollect, API, FTAF, Import, Move Copy, Application, Salesforce, Segmentation, Generic Extension, and Custom Object

You can also query this information using sql, like in the example below:

```
SELECT 
SubscriberKey,
AddMethod
FROM _ListSubscribers WHERE ListID = 1234
```

In above query replace the list id with the id of your All Subscriber’s list id.